# Tiene la palabra superior una connotación positiva?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Una simple definición de superior por Google dice

> Que es más que otra persona o cosa en calidad, cantidad, rango,
>   importancia, etc.

Hay varias definiciones pero las que me interesan van por este sentido.

Sin embargo, si una persona dijera algo así como: "el asesino Fulano es superior a Mengano" , a mi me suena como que se está haciendo apología de un criminal, porque, a mi parecer, la palabra superior le da una connotación positiva a lo que se dice, cuando tal vez lo que el emisor quiere expresar es que un asesino es capaz de matar a más personas que otro sin querer dar a entender en lo más mínimo que esto es bueno, que no lo es. ¿Es así que la palabra superior tiene una connotación positiva o no? De ser así (que tiene una connotación positiva) ¿Existe una palabra para expresar una cantidad más alta y efectiva de algo sin que esto tenga una connotación positiva?

[Superior](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=cq9ZXsbmM4y-5OUP0ua_qA8&q=superior%20significado&oq=superior%20significado&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i70i249j0l3j0i22i30l6.333.3520..3736...2.0..0.118.1988.17j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0i131i70i253j0i10.NkjRuyTdrF4&ved=0ahUKEwjG54jrv_XnAhUMH7kGHVLzD_UQ4dUDCAY&uact=5)

Answer (score 3):

Si uno dijera algo así como "El asesino Fulano es superior a Mengano", en realidad no estaría expresándose bien, o estaría siendo ambiguo a propósito, ya que no se comprende de qué habla. Normalmente se diría "superior *en relación a...*" (cierta cualidad), o algo a tal efecto.

Quizá alguien pueda hablar de un asesino como "superior" a otro, manteniendo una connotación positiva, en un análisis de la trama de una novela policíaca. No se me ocurre otro caso donde pueda ser razonable esta palabra.

Por sus usos habituales yo diría que *superior* por sí sola tiene una connotación positiva **cuando se refiere a cualidades**: "Este vino es superior al promedio" se entiende como "de calidad superior". Si sólo decimos "Este vino es superior" se sobreentiende que se trata de una característica del vino (que por conocimiento general sabemos que es su calidad considerada en general).

Si se habla meramente **de cantidades**, en cambio, *superior* es neutra. "La cifra de muertos es superior a la de todos los años anteriores" es una apreciación objetiva. Al hablar cualitativamente siempre se menciona qué es lo que se está contando o midiendo, y esto es lo que define la connotación de la frase; *superior* queda reducida a una simple comparación numérica.